# Issue in writing regular express

Tags: java, string, qt

How to read  the string from the position (Example)5 to the end of the string in java.

```
    QRegExp StripType(re, Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    int p = StripType.indexIn(line, 0);
    int len = StripType.matchedLength();
    String tmp += line.mid(len);
```

How to convert QT into java

Where re is in the above code is regular expression and i want to covert the above into java i have tried

```
String s =pattern.toString();
int pos =  s.indexOf(line);
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(re).matcher(line); 
if (matcher.find()) { 
System.out.println(matcher.group()); 
} else { 
System.out.println("String contains no character other than that"); 
} 
len = matcher.start();
```

But its not working correct 
    Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

To begin with you should add the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag.

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(re, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(line);
```